# problem in my first project of android studio

Tags: android, project

When I was creating a new project it showed this warning and I do not understand what is it for.
This is the image of the warning it is showing.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oagoi.png)

I changed to 31 and here are some screenshots regarding the issue.
[image][image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the compileSdk to 31 instead of 32 in your build.gradle.

[image]

Comment: I changed it to 31 but when I rebuild it again and clicked on the 'run' button it did not give me the emulator to start creating my app interface instead showed me this error. "Error while waiting for the device: The emulator process for AVD Ankit_mobile has terminated."

Comment: Try creating a new virtual device by clicking on the available device dropdown menu next to the 'run app' button and select 'AVD manager'. There you can create a new virtual device and make sure it runs on like API 30 for example.

Comment: I created a new virtual device again but still, it is showing the same as those screenshots are depicting that I recently added.

Answer (score 0):

change your  compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in build.gradel file

```
compileSdkVersion 31

targetSdkVersion 31
```